# How to create index in a closure around a parsing function in python

Tags: python, pandas, parsing, closures

I'm trying to learn some of the more nuanced features of python, and I have a problem where I need to create a parsing function to pass to pandas.read_csv. It needs to have an index which updates every time the inner function is called. The parsing (inner) function should look something like this:

```
DATA_PERIOD = 0.01 # 1/100 of a second

def outer_func():
    index = 0
    def parser(x):
        index += 1
        datetime = datetime.strptime(index * DATA_PERIOD,'%f')
        return datetime
    return parser
parser = outer_func()
```

... where x is the time index (as a string) and I'm not using it directly due to some funkiness inherent in the dataset, but read_csv requires that argument. However, I am having great difficulty in actually getting something like this working. I have tried wrapping that function in an outer function, but the inner function can't update the index of the outer function (python grants only read-access to out variables for nested functions), and I need it to be updated every time the inner function is called (i.e. every time the function is called by the parser for a new line of data).

EDIT: Made the code example more complete with my attempt at creating a closure, rather than just describing it.

Comment: The function does not use `x`, and `index` is never initialized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go back to wrapping it in an outer function, but use `nonlocal` before the variable you want to mutate.

For example:

```
def outer():
    times_called = 1
    def inner():
        nonlocal times_called
        print('I have been called {} times!'.format(times_called))
        times_called += 1
    return inner

foo = outer()
foo()
foo()
foo()
```

Note this works only in 3.X, for 2.X there are hacky workarounds such as putting the closed over variable in a mutable data structure (e.g. list) and then mutating the list `times_called[0] +=1`

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about the nonlocal statement.